# Very small vertical space between advertisement and question text

Tags: bug, design, advertising

On sites where I see advertisements the vertical space between the ad and the start of the question is very small. [Example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269087/manhwa-that-starts-with-the-emperor-poisoning-the-empress-with-their-child-in-he) from SFF:

[image]

This is distracting to read, and it seems to be inconsistent with the vertical spacing used everywhere else in the design.

A similar effect occurs for sidebar advertisements, although it is less prominent ([from Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90895/pir-sensor-is-already-high-even-though-it-is-not-detecting-any-person)):

[image]

Browser: Firefox 106.0.3 on Ubuntu, but it also occurs in Chrome.

Suggested fix: make the space a bit bigger.

Comment: @AaronBertrand indeed, most likely deleted for some reason. You might be able to find it using `deleted:1` in search, not sure if the "staff" bit is enough without a diamond though. :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I read Meta.SE regularly but I didn't see the previous report, sorry - the problem itself has existed longer though, at least one or two weeks now.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I can see deleted posts, but I've since discovered that I saw this in an internal Slack conversation last week. So close. I don't want to disclose too much but essentially the space that is missing is usually reserved for a "Report this ad" link, and the behavior is different depending on whether you are logged in. They're aware there's a fluctuation but I don't have any info about fix/timeline/etc/

Comment: @AaronBertrand hehe. so we can't report internal SO ads, that make sense. Still, better design choice would be to add a margin when there's no "report ad" link.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Of course. They're still investigating where the margin goes.

Comment: @Shadow I think it's not related to the ad being internal, the second example I put in the question (about the sidebar) also doesn't have a report ad link while this is an external ad. The problem is that the link is not shown at all when you are not logged in (which indeed I am not in both SFF and Arduino).

Comment: Agreed, whose ad it is is not the issue.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed now.